# Adding an onPress Method/Touchable Highlight

Tags: react-native

I am working with a custom component and struggling to add onPress functionality to it. I would love to just add an onPress tag to the component and bind a function to that.. but can't seem to find anywhere how to do so.

I have also tried just using TouchableHighlight, however.. when I do that the whole element disapears. I think it still renders as it it still logs the the custom component has been created.  But I can't figure out how I can change the styling to make it so the custom component still appears in the view...

Here is my code:

```
    <TouchableHighlight>
<CustomEle
    thumbnailSource={{ uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/W3LKLla.png?bust' + Math.random() }}
    imageSource={{ uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/741u15U.png?bust' + Math.random() }}
    style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch' }}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Any help or advice would be a lifesafer! Thanks!

Render MEthod:

```
render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.callThisFunction.bind(this)}>

      <View onPress={this.onBoom()} style={this.props.style}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={[styles.image, this.props.style]}
          source={this.props.placeHolderSource}
        />
        <Animated.Image
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={[styles.image, { opacity: this.state.thumbnailOpacity }, this.props.style]}
          source={this.props.thumbnailSource}
          onLoad={() => this.onLoadThumbnail()}
          blurRadius={this.props.thumbnailBlurRadius}
        />
        <Animated.Image
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={[styles.image, { opacity: this.state.imageOpacity }, this.props.style]}
          source={this.props.imageSource}
          onLoad={() => this.onLoadImage()}
        />
        </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom component wrap your component around a `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableHighlight` and then call a function when you click on your component. So in your case we will call it `CustomEle` and call `callThisFunction`.

```
class CustomEle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.callThisFunction.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  callThisFunction(){
    //Do somthing here
  }
}
```

Comment: Dosen't seem to work.. and makes it so my component basically disapears... I'm wondering if it has anything to do with styling.. I pasted my render component in my question above.. thanks!

Comment: @JoeCaraccio add your TouchableOpacity within your View. So it should be View, TouchableOpacity and then your images within the TouchableOpacity. You also might have to add styling to the TouchableOpacity like flex 1. I'm not sure what your current styling is on your View. Hope this helps.